# More simplistic way of doing OR rewrites in apache2?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, vhosts

Is there a shorter way to get the get the domainname in a regex and forward it in a rewrite than the example below?

Now I catch "every" domain and do a rewrite to www.domain[A|B|C].com.
And I need to catch "*.domain[A|B|C].com" and "domain[A|B|C].com" in every domain too.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On

        #domainA.com
        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domainA\.com$ [OR,NC]
        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.+)\.domainA\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://www.domainA.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        #domainB.com
        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domainB\.com$ [OR,NC]
        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.+)\.domainB\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        #domainC.com
        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domainC\.com$ [OR,NC]
        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(.+)\.domainC\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://www.domainC.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername servername.com

        ServerAlias www.domainA.com www.domainB.com www.domainC.com

        # Server config stuffz here

</VirtualHost>
```

If this is fuzzy, I'll try to explain more :)

--
Regards Falk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your 3 rules in one:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:.+\.)?(domain[ABC]\.com)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* http://www.%1$0 [R=permanent,L]
```

- domainA.com or *.domainA.com can be written as `(?:.+\.)?domainA\.com`:

  - `(.+\.)?` makes subdomain part optional
  - the eventual subdomain part is not reused, so we can use a non capturing subpattern (`(?: ... )`)
- domainA or domainB or domainC = `domain[ABC]` (if for real, it's foo, bar and doe, use `(?:foo|bar|doe)` instead)
- we can reinject the capture from the last RewriteCond to Rewritule. The difference with captures from RewriteRule (its first argument) is that they are prefixed by a `%` instead of `$`. So `%1` will correspond to domainA.com or domainB.com or domainC.com
- I've also rewritten `^\/?(.*)$` + `$1` to `.*` + `$0`:

  - no need to escape `/`, this is not a metacharacter and with Apache regexpes don't have any delimiter (not like preg_* from PHP)
  - `$0` is a special capture which takes the substring that matches the whole pattern (the path - or part of it in a directory context)

EDIT: yes, my bad, I forgot you were not in a directory context: there is no need for a slash between `%1` and `$0`, the substring captured by `$0` already include the leading slash of the path of the URL.

Comment: that is just beautiful, the example I searched for was (?:foo|bar|doe).
For the moment I get just www.//, but I will se if I can see whats going wrong and update the comment/question/answer..

Comment: I've done some testing over at -> [link](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)
But I cannot get the expected result, with RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:.+\.)(?:foo\.com|bar\.com|doe.\com)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule .* http://www.%1/$0 [R=permanent,L]

Comment: Humm, cannot edit comments..
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:.+\.)(?:foo\.com|bar\.com|doe.\com)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule .* http://www.%1/$0 [R=permanent,L]

Comment: Replace `(?:foo\.com|bar\.com|doe.\com)` by `((?:foo|bar|doe)\.com)`. You need a capturing subpattern the domain.

Comment: Now your regexp work, the only thing is that I have a http://www.foo.com// when just entering the fqdn with no subpage. http://www.foo.com/bleh/ works prefectly.

Comment: (explanation of my statement, I meant that I implemented you regexp wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The solution as @julp answered ended in my case like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:.+\.)?(foo\.com|bar\.com|doe\.com)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* http://www.%1$0 [R=permanent,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername servername.com

        ServerAlias www.foo.com www.bar.com www.foobar.com
        # Server config stuffz here

</VirtualHost>
```

The only thing I had to do different was:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.%1/$0 [R=permanent,L]
```

changed to, without the trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.%1$0 [R=permanent,L]
```

There is some talk about it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/24130/why-do-i-get-a-double-trailing-slash-depending-on-where-my-rewriterule-is-locate